# When I use pylint in python code this message comes to me "no module named ..."

Tags: cmd, pylint

Here is my error message:

```bash
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\python project\first project> pylint.exe  c:/Users/pc/Desktop/python project/first project/ahmed.py
************* Module c:/Users/pc/Desktop/python
c:/Users/pc/Desktop/python:1:0: F0001: No module named c:/Users/pc/Desktop/python (fatal)
************* Module project/first
project/first:1:0: F0001: No module named project/first (fatal)
************* Module project/ahmed.py
project/ahmed.py:1:0: F0001: No module named project/ahmed.py (fatal)
```

I use `vscode`

`pip` latest version

Python 3.10

Comment: You are using files paths with empty spaces in the: `python project\first project`. So you need to use quotes around these paths to protect the empty spaces: `pylint.exe  "c:/Users/pc/Desktop/python project/first project/ahmed.py"`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run pylint on a file that is not in the same directory as the Python interpreter. You need to make sure that the file you are trying to run pylint on is in the same directory as the Python interpreter. You can do this by either moving the file to the same directory as the Python interpreter or by specifying the full path to the file when running pylint.

For example, if the file is located in the same directory as the Python interpreter, you can run pylint like this: `pylint ahmed.py`.

If the file is located in a different directory, you can run pylint like this: `pylint /path/to/ahmed.py`.